# is "ausführlich" comprehensive?

Tags: meaning, german-to-english, adjective

The Duden says that "ausführlich" is "eingehend, in allen Einzelheiten, detailliert". But is it "comprehensive" in the sense that it covers every aspect ? or at least every relevant/significant aspect ?

In other words, does "ausführlich" convey a sense of exhaustivity, or is it just a sense of "detailliert" / "genau" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

"Ausführlich" just means that something is extensive or an explanation is providing much detail. If you want to explicitly express that *everything* is covered, then you would want to resort to descriptions like "umfänglich", "umfassend" or "vollständig" or even "allumfassend" or "vollumfänglich".

Comment: Good answer. I would just add that _vollumfänglich_ is lawyer-jargon.

Comment: "Vollständig" might be the closest fit for comprehensive.

Comment: Danke für die klare und ausführliche Antwort!